# How to Optimize the below query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select 
   c.std_date,c.conf_link,c.conf_link as 
   link,c.conf_id,c.url_id,c.entry_source,c.data_source,c.title,c.conf_domain,
   c.descrip, c.std_loc, c.std_practices,c.region, co.company_id,co.company,co.home_url 
from 
   conferences c, companies co 
where c.org_id= co.company_id and c.org_id in   
    (12,47,173,120,102,83,95,172,200,78,199,523,134,123,30,185,103,202,
     159,133,178,49,161,146,17,212,136,43,107,147,142,3, 205,171,177,443,175,74,156,41,42,128,5,7,62,37,195,68,89,8,39,85,126,36,24,206,208,201,150,152,168,59,97,28,11,116,140,98,117,51,174,93,192,50,617,176,101,194,527,61,179,170,145,40,92,257,149,48,88,486,20,111,106,203,19,31,163,81,25,38,623,628,642,643,644,645,647,677,711,712,713,6173,6174,6176,6177,6184,6185,6186,6189,6191,6207,6210,6211,6212,6214,6215,6217,6218,6219,6222,6223,6224,6294,6297,6298,6300,6301,6302,7468,7469,7471,7472,7473,7474,7475,7476,7477,7478,7479,7480,7481,7482,7483,7484,7489,7490,7491,7493,7494,7495,7496,7497,7498,7499,7500,7501,7502,7503,7504,7505,7506,7507,7508,7509,7510,7511,7512,7513,7514,7515,7516,7517,7518,7519,7520,7521,7522,7523,7525,7526,7527,7528,7529,7530,7531,7532,7533,7534,7535,7536,7537,7538,7539,7540,7541,7542,7543,7544,7545,7546,7547,7548,7549,7550,7551,7552,7553,7554,7555,7556,7557,7558,7559,7560,7562,7566) 
and conf_id !='' and (region !='123' and region not like 'webinar%') and std_date >= '2013-04-17' and std_date <= '2013-04-24' and (data_source like 'E%' OR data_source like 'A%') and region != '' and org !='' and title not like '%groupcast%' and relevance >= 0 order by std_date desc limit 3500
```

Comment: To me it looks as a piece of art, why would you want to optimize it?

Comment: I need data from  conferences and  companies table where conferences has all these id's. Pl help to make this better

Comment: The best way to optimize that is to open it in a code editor, select all of the text, and hit `Delete`, and then start over and write a new `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you need. You wouldn't have to type the `id`s manually

```
where c.org_id= co.company_id and c.org_id in (Select id from Conferences)
```

Comment: at last some constructive answer :) @codingbiz, asking for myself, another way of doing it would be a left join with Conferences on left side?

Comment: @codingbiz... id's are coming form search.

Comment: What search? You mean users type all those Ids?

Comment: @codingbiz .. Users can select these from multiselect.

Comment: @Ejay It actually should be an INNER JOIN

Comment: Then you must be generating query from code - including the IDs? You could take the generated output and run in mysql, preceding it with EXPLAIN

Comment: Thanks everyone.. wish you all have a good evening.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's quite easy:

- just look at the "explain ..." first
- look, what is causing too many rows
- reformulate for better results.

I can see no real restrictions despite of the date-range. Is std_date a datetime-field? Then adding  time 00:00:00 could help (if there is any index at all). I prefer inner join too,

from conferences c
 inner join companies co on c.org_id= co.company_id

but that improves not speed.

"like ..."  and  especially "not like ..." are suspects.

try if the condition like E% or like A% is much faster with only one candidate (index usage if any index is on that field) - then make a UNION of both single queries.

"data_source like " could get a little help from text-index.

Comment: @flaschenpost.. thanks I got that.. You are the best!!!